# How can I trigger a boxcollider2d

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have no idea why my trigger system isn't working
I have 2 objects, both with box colider 2D, the first object is tagged Player and Box Colider 2D isn't set to trigger, the second one is untagged, Box Collider 2D is set to trigger and contains the following code :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
   
public class hit : MonoBehaviour
{      
    public void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {          
        if (other.gameObject.tag == "Player") 
        {               
            Debug.Log("triggered");
        }
    }
}
```

Nothing happens when the first one passes through the second one.

Could someone help me?

Comment: You have put in methods for the 3d trigger not 2d. Change th m to 2d and it will probably work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### you probably need the [OnTriggerEnter2D()](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnTriggerEnter2D.html) method, as your collider is 2D

```cs
void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
{
    Debug.Log("GameObject collided with " + collision.name);
}
```

Comment: no problem, this is basic knowledge for me - flexxx